Install Packages for Python3.12 without setuptools or distutils
I'm asking a bit of a repeat of this question, because I don't believe the comments interpreted the essence of the question, or addressed it properly.
I would like to install Python v3.12, NOT as a replacement for the Ubuntu python requirements, but to run my own programs (in VSCode or Terminal for example). I understand that distutils has been deprecated since v3.10, so I would need to install setuptools in order to install things like scipy andnumpy via
python3.12 -m pip install numpy

However, when I try
python3.12 -m pip install setuptools

I also get the same warning ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils' and am unable to proceed.

Check out miniforge3, used to set up environments for older python (used for sagemath in Ubuntu 24.04 needing python 3.10).
